# How to calculate the needed energy to make something spin around its axis at a certain rate?

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics, rotation

An object is floating into space. How much energy is required to make it spin around its own axis with a rate of x RPM? How does this calculation look?

And does this calculation change if the object is in motion? Does the calculation change depending on what kind of motion it is in (linear vs rotational). And as for rotational, it can spin about its own axis, which would probably lower the needed energy to make it spin, or it can orbit around another point. So, what is the calculation and how does linear and rotational (both about its own axis and orbiting another point) motion affect the calculation?

Comment: Here is the formula to find rotational KE; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Rotating_bodies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no friction, the amount of energy is simply the difference in rotational kinetic energy $K_R$ after and before the rotation was established:

$$\Delta K_R=\frac12I\omega^2\tag{1}$$

Note that 'own axis' is really a meaningless term: an object can be made to rotate **about any axis** (even one that doesn't run through the object). In $(1)$, $I$ is the moment of inertia **about the chosen axis**.

In physics we don't really use $RPM$, instead we use *angular velocity*, $\omega$:

$$\omega=2\pi\frac{RPM}{60}\text{ in }\mathrm{s^{-1}}$$

> And does this calculation change if the object is in motion? Does the
> calculation change depending on what kind of motion it is in (linear
> vs rotational).

Linear and rotational motion are perfectly independent of each other. An object may be cruising along at velocity, say $v$, thus having a translational kinetic energy $K_T=\frac12mv^2$. At some point a *net torque* may then cause it to start rotating about some axis. This will not change $v$ or $K_T$. The total kinetic energy $\Sigma K=K_T+K_R$.

> And as for rotational, it can spin about its own axis, which would
> probably lower the needed energy to make it spin, or it can orbit
> around another point.

No, both motions (and associated energies) are  independent of each other.

It's not wise to speak of a rotation *'around another point'*: rotation is **ALWAYS** about an axis, not a point.

Comment: What is the "moment of inertia about the chosen axis", or "I"? Is it the rotational kinetic energy equivalent to mass in the formula for (linear) kinetic energy?

Comment: @A.Kvåle Yes, that's correct!